# How to use eval() whit kivy TextInput?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have several TextInputs in my Python kivy program. And I want a function that multiply, divide or add the inputs and display the result in a different label. But if the inputs for example are 40 and 60 the label only displays 4060 instead of 100.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def numbers_submit(self):
    ti = self.ids.one_input.text
    fi = self.ids.two_input.text
    ei = self.ids.three_input.text

    fl = self.ids.result_label 

    fl.text = eval("ti + fi")
```

## i have also tried:

```
   fl.text = eval(str("ti + fi"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert the `TextInput` text/string to integer using `int()` function
- Convert the result from integer to string using `str()` function

## Snippets

```
def numbers_submit(self):
    ti = int(self.ids.one_input.text)
    fi = int(self.ids.two_input.text)
    ei = self.ids.three_input.text

    fl = self.ids.result_label

    fl.text = str(eval('ti + fi'))
```

## Output

[image: Result: 40 + 60 = 100]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)